# Doing timezone conversion while using BeanUtils.copyProperties

Tags: java, hibernate, timezone, date-conversion, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a Hibernate mapped model class as follows,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "User_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "User_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name = "User_SEQ")
    private Integer id;

    private Date createdOn;
}
```

I have another model class as follows which I use for the response from a REST API. The object of this class essentially gets serialized into JSON

```
public class UserDTO {
    private Integer id;

    private Date createdOn;
}
```

Since the variable names are the same, I am using BeanUtils.copyProperties to copy the value of all fields from User to UserDTO (Currently showing only 2 fields above for simplicity)

Data is stored in GMT in the database, hence the createdOn field contains the TIMESTAMP in GMT. I want to return the Date in local time zone e.g. "Europe/Copenhagen". For this I am using the following code (using apache commons),

```
java.util.Date defaultValue = null;
DateConverter dateConverter = new DateConverter(defaultValue);
dateConverter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Copenhagen"));
BeanUtilsBean beanUtilsBean = BeanUtilsBean.getInstance();
beanUtilsBean.getConvertUtils().register(dateConverter, java.util.Date.class);
BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDTO, user);
```

The code executes, but userDTO still contains the date in GMT. time zone conversion is not working. What am I missing here?

EDIT1:

I have tried checking by manually passing a date as follows,

```
@Test
public void testBeanUtilsDateConverter() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("\ntestBeanUtilsDateConverter - Start");
    Date date = new GregorianCalendar(2014, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 11, 18, 30, 10).getTime();
    Date newDate = new Date();

    DateConverter converter = new DateConverter();
    converter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Copenhagen"));

    BeanUtilsBean beanUtilsBean = BeanUtilsBean.getInstance();
    beanUtilsBean.getConvertUtils().deregister(java.util.Date.class);
    beanUtilsBean.getConvertUtils().register(converter, java.util.Date.class);

    System.out.println(newDate);
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(newDate, date);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(newDate);

    System.out.println("testBeanUtilsDateConverter - End");
}
```

Output:

```
testBeanUtilsDateConverter - Start
Fri Jun 02 14:04:08 IST 2017
Tue Feb 11 18:30:10 IST 2014
Tue Feb 11 18:30:10 IST 2014
testBeanUtilsDateConverter - End
```

So the BeanUtils is definitely copying the date to the target, but the converter is either not getting called or not doing anything for some reason

EDIT2 - Using Custom Converter

```
class MyDateConverter implements Converter {

    public MyDateConverter() {
        System.out.println("Instantiating MyDateConverter");
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Class Date, Object value) {
        System.out.println("Inside convert()");
        if (value == null) {
            System.out.println("Value is null");
            return (Date) null;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Doing date conversion");
            Date date = new GregorianCalendar(2015, Calendar.JANUARY, 12, 9, 45, 15).getTime();
            return date;
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void testCustomDateConverter() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("\ntestCustomDateConverter - Start");
    Date date = new GregorianCalendar(2014, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 11, 18, 30, 10).getTime();
    Date newDate = new Date();

    BeanUtilsBean beanUtilsBean = BeanUtilsBean.getInstance();
    beanUtilsBean.getConvertUtils().deregister(java.util.Date.class);
    beanUtilsBean.getConvertUtils().register(new MyDateConverter(), java.util.Date.class);

    System.out.println(newDate);
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(newDate, date);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(newDate);

    System.out.println("testCustomDateConverter - End");
}
```

Output:

```
testCustomDateConverter - Start
Instantiating MyDateConverter
Fri Jun 02 14:04:09 IST 2017
Tue Feb 11 18:30:10 IST 2014
Tue Feb 11 18:30:10 IST 2014
testCustomDateConverter - End
```

Again the same result. The custom converter is getting instantiated, but the convert method is not called. I even tried a custom Long converter to check if it's something to do with using the Date class, but even that was not getting called. There is something missing in the registration part that BeanUtils is not able to call the overridden convert function.

Comment: So if I understand, you want to store the date in GMT in the database... but when the user accesses the data, it should display in their own time zone?

Comment: Dates are stored in GMT in the database. User makes a REST API call to the server and sends his timezone and date format information in the request header. The server retrieves the data from the database and needs to convert the date to the user's timezone before sending it back to the user as a JSON response. This is a pretty common scenario. I could have done the copy field by field and used SimpleDateFormat to do the conversion, but I want to do it using BeanUtils.copyProperties so that it gets done by default

Comment: Have you manually tested the Date Converter?

Comment: No.Its the DateConverter from Apache commons. import org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.DateConverter; How do I test this?

Comment: So I would try passing it a date manually to make sure that the data converts correctly. Then I would try making a custom converter which just prints out some debug statement to make sure the converter is being triggered.

Comment: Updated the query with the code to pass date manually. Didn't work. I will try the custom date converter next. Thanks

Comment: A `Date` does not contain a time zone (it’s a common misconception, though, so don’t be ashamed :-) Though a `GregorianCalendar` does, what I would do would be switch over to the modern date and time classes and use a `ZonedDateTime`. Maybe you can even persuade Hibernate to store the date-time as an `Instant`, another one of the modern classes. Then conversion will be straightforward (conversion to and from `Date` can be done too).

Comment: Other option, just store as `Instant` in `User.createdOn` and only format into Copenhagen time zone when displaying to the user. I think I would consider this cleaner.

Comment: I have used GregorianCalendar as an example. The issue is that the converter method of BeanUtilsBean is not getting called, nor is the custom converter method. If that gets called, I can do all the magic of time zone transformation inside that.